# Чем заменить transition для марджина, чтобы избежать jiggle-эффекта при ховере?

Tags: html, css

есть примерно такая конструкция на сайте:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbNOOp
При наведении на изображение возникает так называемый jiggle-эффект (дрожание на полпикселя). В браузерных редакторах кода он ведет себя немного не так, как при запуске самой страницы. В примере на codepen можно при наведении на картинку понять, что я имею в виду, глядя на кнопку под ней. При запуске же оригинальной страницы в firefox крайние блоки ряда с этим же эффектом двигают центральный, а в IE11, к примеру, дрожит само изображение, на которое наводишь курсор. Как я понял, его возникновение связано с тем, что применяется `transition` по отношению к `margin` (т.е. не стоит применять это к отступам, окружающим непосредственно объект). Есть ли не слишком витиеватые способы решить проблему, сохранив остальной функционал? Изменять рамку вместо размера не вариант в связи со сложным фоном (специально оставил), `position: absolute;` тоже не применить к изображению в связи с конструкцией.
Спасибо.

```css
html, body{
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2ab0fb;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, #fff, #000);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, #fff, #000);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, #fff, #000);
  background: radial-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #000);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.item-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.item-list>li {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


.list li {
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  transition: .25s all;
}

.link:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.link>div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: .25s all;
}

.link:hover>div {
  transform: translate(-15%, -15%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="item-list list">
  <li>
<a class="link" href="#" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg);">
  <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200.jpg);"></div>
</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Кнопка</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a class="link" href="#" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg);">
  <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200.jpg);"></div>
</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Кнопка</a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a class="link" href="#" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg);">
   <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200.jpg);"></div>
 </a>
 <a class="btn" href="#">Кнопка</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: интересно, у меня в fireffox работает ровненько, никаких дрожаний или сдвигов

Comment: @Isaev вы на Codepen запускаете? У меня тоже Firefox, на этой странице сниппетом код выполняется без проблем, в отличие от кода по ссылке.

Comment: @Isaev
Вот так выглядит в IE (внимательно см. на цифру 1):
https://i.ibb.co/C7dTyNr/ie.gif
А так в Firefox (см. на соседний блок):
https://i.ibb.co/6ZHLSKF/firefox.gif

Comment: да с Codepen. Этого глюка не наблюдаю. Работает так же, как приведённый на этой странице

Comment: @Isaev а вот так у меня ведет себя Codepen: https://i.ibb.co/KLmrYx8/codepen.gif (см. на кнопку). Но не суть. Суть вопроса в том, что проблема встречается повсеместно, и даже известна причина. Хотел бы выяснить обходные пути для моего случая.